# How to access the checked property of a Delphi 2009 ribbon button on runtime?

Tags: delphi, taction

I want to reset the "checked" property of all TAction objects of a ribbon to false when clicking on any ribbon button and then only set it true on the pressed button.
But I did not yet find a way to access all the "checked" properties of the ActionManager's Actions.
I think I need to loop through the actionmanager's actionlist... however, but I did not yet find the right way to do.
I'd be very glad if someone could give me some hint on this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you set the GroupIndex property of the actions, you shouldn't need to write any additional code at all. That property tells actions that they're part of a group, so they automatically uncheck everything else when any one gets checked, just like a radio button.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this question has anything to do with ribbons, or with Delphi 2009. Actions were introduced in Delphi 4. Consider either removing those tags or editing the question to make those details relevant.

Comment: @Rob: great points on the tags, and admit being complicit in mis-tagging.  Have edited per your suggestion.  Great answer, BTW!

Comment: @Rob: You are absolutely right, don't know why I missed that.
This solves my problem ;)
Though the answer below is also very helpful, as I may need to access some properties later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TActionManager` descends from `TCustomActionList`, so whatever you can do with the latter, you can do with the former. It has two properties you'll need to use, `Actions`, which is the array property that gives you access to all the list's actions, and `ActionCount`, which tells you how many there are. Use them to write an ordinary loop, like this:

```
var
  i: Integer;
  Contained: TContainedAction;
  Action: TCustomAction;
begin
  for i := 0 to Pred(ActionList.ActionCount) do begin
    Contained := ActionList[i]; // shorthand for ActionList.Actions[i]
    if not (Contained is TCustomAction) then
      continue; // Doesn't have Checked property

    Action := TCustomAction(Contained);
    Action.Checked := False;
  end;
end;
```

Action lists can hold lots of kinds of actions, and they don't all have `Checked` properties. That property is introduced in `TCustomAction`, so the code above also filters out the things that don't descend from that class.

Comment: Though rob solved my specific question another way, this answer is also very helpful for understanding how all this action stuff works.
Thanks!